# Increase fonts for mobile devices with Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, mobile, fonts, responsive-design, zurb-foundation-5

I've created a **clean new** web project with Zurb **Foundation** 5. On desktop and laptop it looks great. I use `rem` units for font sizes. On small devices the layout is responsive but the **font is much smaller** - I guess because of higher **pixel density**.

The solutions ([this for example](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/22683-increase-base-font-size-on-mobile-devices)) provided on Zurb's forum didn't work for me.

Any any ideas will be very much appreciated.

**Update**:

Here's what I found working for many devices:

```
@media #{$retina} {
 font-size: 200%;
}
```

However it doesn't cover everything, for example Samsung Galaxy II device, for which the font stays small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that starting with mobile-first is the way to go. So in my css something like this works with small devices:

```
@media #{$small-up} {
 font-size: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have mobile viewport declared.

```
<!-- Mobile Meta -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta class="foundation-mq">
```